# Getting body part headers with IMAP C-Client

Tags: c, imap, mime

I am using [UW IMAP c-client](http://www.washington.edu/imap/) v. 2007e and I couldn't find the following function: I need to retrieve a header of certain body part. I.e., the mail message contains multiple body parts, and one of them is an attachment looking like this:

```
  --_004_57D6D2035A40B8ECEBA59CB9C13F52A1334093MBXC18_
  Content-Type: text/plain; name="func.txt"
  Content-Description: func.txt
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="func.txt"; size=604;
    creation-date="Thu, 12 Aug 2010 18:41:40 GMT";
    modification-date="Thu, 12 Aug 2010 18:41:40 GMT"
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

  ...blah-blah-blah in base64...
```

Now, I can retrieve the blah-blah part with `imap_fetchbody()` but I don't see the function that can give me only the headers part (or headers+body, that would be OK too). I can get whole message text, but then I'd have to parse it myself into parts, which I don't want to do. Is there a way I could make c-client retrieve this header for certain part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `MIME` section of the part.  [From the IMAP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5):

> The MIME part specifier refers to the [MIME-IMB] header for
> this part.

The c-client function for doing a `FETCH` is:

```
long imap_msgdata (MAILSTREAM *stream,unsigned long msgno,char *section,
                   unsigned long first,unsigned long last,STRINGLIST *lines,
                   long flags)
```

So if you want the headers from part 2.3 of message #8 (for instance), you'd call it as:

```
imap_msgdata(stream, 8, "2.3.MIME", 0, 0, null, FT_PEEK);
```

(`FT_PEEK` keeps the message from being marked as `\Seen`.  If you want to mark the message read, pass `0` as the last argument.)

Comment: Looks like there's also more generic one - `mail_fetch_mime()`. But that seems to be what I need, thanks.